# How do you add custom form helpers to formtastic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, twitter-bootstrap, formtastic

I love formtastic but I'm confused by how to add custom form fields to the built in ones. For example, I'd like to use [recurring_select](https://github.com/GetJobber/recurring_select)

I've read [the docs](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic#modified--custom-inputs) but it's a little over my head. Is there an easy way to do it?

Just to make it more interesting/complicated I'm also using [formtastic-bootstrap](https://github.com/mjbellantoni/formtastic-bootstrap)